# how do i cache specific table with MySQL and asp.net framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to cache frequently used data in asp.net with MySQL and .net framework 2.0. is there any way to do it with asp.net without using caching technique provided by MySQL i.e. query cache or table cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cache` variable and put your data in that variable.
First bring the values in `Data-Set` or `List` or `Data-Table` put it in the `Cache` as follows

Suppose you have data in a data-set ds then

```
Cache.Insert("CacheTableA", ds, null, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

It will cache your data-set ds for 10 minutes.
And while using cast it from the Cache as

```
  DataSet ds=(DataSet)Cache["CacheTableA"];
  ....
```

You can go through this link to understand caching in Asp.net http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_caching.htm